# SFP record setup for single server

Tags: exchange-2007, spf

I have a single server

Domain: mycompany.com
Server: mail.mycompany.com
MX: mail.mycompany.com

Would this record work

> "v=spf1 ip4:38.28.xx.yy
>   a:mail.mycompany.com
>   mx:mail.mycompany.com ~all"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use simple:

```
"v=spf1 mx -all"
```

and test it(http://www.kitterman.com/spf/validate.html)